# Protobuf Partially Copy vector into repeated filed

Tags: c++, copy, protocol-buffers, stdcopy

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499641/copy-a-stdvector-to-a-repeated-field-from-protobuf-with-memcpy), it is answered how a vector can be copied into a repeated field by using `fMessage.mutable_samples() = {fData.begin(), fData.end()};` ( and the other direction works too ).

But how about a partial copy?
Would the below work?

```cpp
std::copy(
  fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2,
  fMessage.mutable_samples()->begin() + 3
);
```

In this scenario `fMessage` has already allocated elements in the `samples` field, and `std::copy` would overwrite the items already present in `fMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a program to test this, and it seems that using `std::copy` works!

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message messagetest{
    repeated float samples = 6;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "message.pb.h"

int main(){
  std::vector<float> fData(10);
  messagetest fMessage;
  std::generate(fData.begin(),fData.end(),[&fMessage](){
    static float num = 0.0;
    num += 1.0;
    fMessage.add_samples(0.0);
    return num;
  });
  for(const float& f : fData)
     std::cout << "[" << f << "]";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  
  std::copy(
    fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2,
    fMessage.mutable_samples()->begin() + 3
  );
  
  for(const float& f : fMessage.samples())
     std::cout << "[" << f << "]";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
[0][0][0][4][5][6][7][8][0][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspect API of [RepeatedField](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field).

IMO you should use this:

```cpp
fMessage.mutable_samples()->Add(fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2);
// or
fMessage.mutable_samples()->Assign(fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2);
```

Comment: So the way I understand `Assign` overwrites the first `std::distance(fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() -2)` elements with the contents in `fData`, right? 
Is there a usecase for when the Assign should start from `fMessage.mutable_samples()->begin() + 3` ? Should `(fMessage.mutable_samples() + 3)->Assign(fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2);` work?

Comment: I tested it out and my suggestion doesn't work, and unfortunately using `Assign` reduces the size of the repeated field to the given range, and that is not desired behaviour

Comment: Meanwhile I took the liberty of adding an answer based on yours to the linked question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71482580/1467600 If you'd like I already mentioned you but if you'd like I can delete my answer so you can post yours.

Answer (score 1):

If `samples` are primitive types, e.g. int32, double, you can use the `Add` method to append a range of items the end of `samples`:

```
fMessage.mutable_samples()->Add(fData.begin() + 3, fData.end() - 2);
```

If `samples` are string or message type, and you're using protobuf 3.16 or latter, then you're lucky, and you can use the solutions mentioned above.

However, if your protobuf is older than 3.16, you have to do it in a loop to add a range of items of string or message type:

```
for (auto iter = fData.begin() + 3; iter != fData.end() - 2; ++iter)
    *(fMessage.add_samples()) = *iter;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! What I was asking for is actually a way to modify already allocated data. I will update my question to reflect that.